# Scraping HTML DOM elements using HtmlAgilityPack in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-agility-pack

I am Scraping HTML DOM elements using HtmlAgilityPack in ASP.NET. currently my code is loading all the href links which means that sublinks of sublinks also . But I need only the depending URL of my domain URL. I don't know how to write code for it. Can any one help me to do this?
Here is my code:

```
public void GetURL(string strGetURL)
{
    var getHtmlSource = new HtmlWeb();
    var document = new HtmlDocument(); 
try
{
    document = getHtmlSource.Load(strGetURL);
    var aTags = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a"); 
    if (aTags != null)
    {
        outputurl.Text = string.Empty;
        int _count = 0;
        foreach (var aTag in aTags)
        {
            string strURLTmp;
            strURLTmp = aTag.Attributes["href"].Value;
            if (_count != 0)
            {
                if (!CheckDuplicate(strURLTmp))
                {
                    lstResults.Add(strURLTmp);
                    outputurl.Text += strURLTmp + "\n";
                    counter++; 
                    GetURL(strURLTmp);
                }
            }
            _count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by *"..depending URL of my domain URL"*?

Answer (score 0):

If you meant to get URL that contains specific domain, you can change the XPath to be :

```
//a[contains(@href, 'your domain here')]
```

Or if you prefer LINQ than XPath :

```
var aTags = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a"); 
if (aTags != null)
{
    ....
    var relevantLinks = aTags.Where(o => o.GetAttributeValue("href", "")
                                          .Contains("your domain here")
                                    );
    ....
}
```

`GetAttributeValue()` is a better way to get value of an attribute using HAP. Instead of returning `null` which may cause exception, this method returns the 2nd parameter when the attribute is not found in the context node.